# Docker + React App - Docker run command doesn't open up localhost

Tags: node.js, reactjs, docker, npm, dockerfile

I'm having trouble with running Docker (I'm a total beginner at it) with my React app. This was given as a coding challenge so I was given these Docker commands:

- docker build --tag app-name .
- docker run -it -p 7357:80 app-name

Here is my dockerfile:
    FROM node:6-wheezy

```
WORKDIR /srv/tenor-frontend-test/

COPY package.json package-lock.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY . .

EXPOSE 80

ENV NODE_JS_PORT=80

CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

My start script in package.json:

```
"start": "PORT=7357 react-scripts start"
```

Using "npm start" in my terminal opens up localhost fine but when I run the "docker run" command, it prints exactly what happens with "npm start" but no browser opens and localhost:7357 doesn't work.

I'm hoping this is just a dockerfile issue since "npm start" works fine?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does your React App listen on 7357?

Comment: @ufxmeng I believe the script in my package.json: "start": "PORT=7357 react-scripts start" should take care of that. Please let me know if I'm mistaken.

Comment: If your React App listen on 7537, you should expose the same port 7537 on the container to the host instead of port 80.

Comment: @ufxmeng gave that a try (switched to EXPOSE 7357 in dockerfile) but no change

Comment: Are you expecting the browser to open? It won't open in your host OS, since the container is running its own OS, so if anything it'll try and open a browser inside the container. Have you tried manually navigating to http://localhost:80 (with your old config)?

Comment: @Alex I manually navigate to localhost but there's never a connection